# Why Isn't jquery Alert working?

Tags: jquery

This keeps happening the jQuery alert doesn't work for seeming no reason. This is happening on 3 or 4 of my js files. Everything else works fine, except for `alert()` or `console.log()`.

Here is the files posted on the bottom of the view:

```cs
@section Scripts 
{
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.rateit.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/profile.js"></script>
}
```

Here is `profile.js`:

```js
$(function () {

alert("hi");

var confirmationId;
var time = false;

$(".contact").on('click', function () {
    $("#contactModal").modal();
});

$(".sendMessage").on('click', function () {
    var email = "nickys2211@gmail.com";
    var body = $("#Message").val();


    $.post("/Authentication/sendEmail", { email: email, body: body}, function () {

    });
});
$(".hiredButton").on('click', function () {
    $("#hireModal").modal();
    var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
    var userName = $("#userLastName").val();
    $("#hireMessage").val("Hi, " + firstName + " can you please confirm that we hired you? \n \n Thanks! \n The " + userName + " Family");
});
$(".sendConfirmationMessage").on('click', function () {

    var userId = $(".hiredButton").data('userid');
    var workerid = $(".hiredButton").data('workerid');
    var userConfirmed = true;
    var email = "nickys2211@gmail.com";
    var body = $("#hireMessage").val();
    $.post("/Authentication/ConfirmHire1", { userId: userId, workerid: workerid, userConfirmed: userConfirmed }, function (confoId) {
        confirmationId = confoId;
        $.post("/Authentication/sendConfirmationEmail", { email: email, body: body, confirmationId: confirmationId }, function () {

        });
    });



});
$(".pastJobs").on('click', function () {
    $("#salesList").modal();
});
$(".times").on('click', function () {
    time = !time;
    if (time == true) {
        $(".timeAvailable").show();
        $(".times").text("Hide Times Available")
    }
    else if (time == false) {
        $(".timeAvailable").hide();
        $(".times").text("See Times Available")
    }
});


});
```

Comment: Does the rest of the code works?

Comment: Try removing the $ from the function

Comment: That first alert on the first line of the function?  If that's not working then that suggests an error in the JavaScript.  Are there any errors on the JavaScript console?  Is jQuery loading at all?

Comment: Yes Everything else is working

Comment: @Spykee: There are *many* instances of `$` in this code, can you be specific as to which one you suspect is incorrect?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `$` at the start of the function on line 1 in profile.js, but nevermind it will probably not change anything

Comment: @Spykee: That's referencing the jQuery object.  Removing it would be a syntax error, as the resulting code would be trying to call a function on nothing.  (Or, if not a syntax error, at least unexpected behavior.)

Comment: Can something be wrong with visual studio?

Comment: @N.Sch: Something *can* be wrong with Visual Studio, but I don't see how that's relevant at this time.  Checking your browser console and stepping through this in your debugger would be very relevant.

Comment: Did that, there's nothing there.

Comment: Out of my 4 or 5 javascript files only 1 is working I tried copying and pasting from the one that wasn't working to the one that was and it still worked ! So there is clearly nothing wrong with the code?

Comment: Now after doing nothing it suddenly started working. I wish I knew what was going on!!!

Comment: Really? You must have done something... Well, congratulations!